# Setting up slurm on a cluster

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, hpc, slurm

My IT admin has setup a cluster with 3 nodes, which is administered via Windows server. VMs are hosted via Hyper-V, including an Ubuntu VM to which a substantial portion of the cluster's resources have been allocated. Does anyone have any experience/success with setting up slurm for job scheduling on a Linux VM hosted on Hyper-V? Existing examples I've found online for setting up slurm don't seem to be working, with a litany of errors. If anyone can point me to some general steps used to setup slurm, would be appreciated.

Edits: have added some errors I am seeing below...

Errors I am getting include:
when I scontrol ping:
** RESTORE SLURMCTLD DAEMON TO SERVICE **

and for sinfo --Node --long
slurm_load_partitions: Unable to contact slurm controller (connect failure)

scontrol show daemons does work, returning:
slurmctld slurmd

However, scontrol show config gives me:
slurm_load_ctl_conf error: Unable to contact slurm controller (connect failure)

I have successfully setup slurm just recently on other machines and have never had any such errors. Have tried googling these, no luck so far re any suggestions I have seen on forums.

Comment: The errors you encounter would be helpful. The fact that it's a VM should not matter.

Comment: That it's on a VM should make zero difference to whatever issues you're facing

Comment: Sounds like slurmctld is not running. Check its logfile.

Comment: Thanks a lot; looking into the log file helped; everything is up and running now. Basically, there were a number of permissions' issues, has to chmod a couple of files and folder locations and now everything is working fine.